# find parent-backgroundcolor not transparent

Tags: jquery

I try to find the nearest parent with a backgroundcolor not transparent.

The first code works, it finds the parent, but there the color is transparent.

```
bg = (e.parentsUntil($(this).has().css("background-color"))).css("background-color");
```

So I struggle with this:

```
bg = (e.parentsUntil($(this).has().css("background-color") <> 'transparent' ).css("background-color");
```

There is a minor problem, that chrome defines transparent with rgba(0,0,0,0) but this should be possible with an or statement as soon the first hurdle is taken.

Comment: You really should have a look at the documentations of [`.parentsUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) and [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: @Andreas I did so... thats why the first code works... but I do not get how to exclude transparent

Comment: `.parentsUntil()` expects a selector or an element. `.has()` expects a selector or an element, hence `$(this).has()` will return an empty set. `.css("background-color")` executed on an empty set will return `undefined`. So you're calling `e.parentsUntil(undefined)` which returns all its parents up to and including `<html>` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf5e0und/))

Comment: It took me some time to realize that I am on the wrong track. Sure you are right! I have a break and go over it again. Thanks so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!
I just found a way to do this.

**For Chrome and Opera**, you have to check for the computed value `rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead of `transparent`.

**For Firefox and Internet Explorer**, you have to check for `transparent`.

In the below snippet, a red border is added on the `div` which is not transparent (grey background).
And a blue border is added to the ones that are transparent... Just for you to see.
;)

```js
$(".test").click(function(e){
  
  var parents = $(e.target).parents("div");
  parents.each(function(i){
    console.log( "element #"+i);
    console.log( "Background: "+$(this).css('background') );
    console.log( "Background-color: "+$(this).css('background-color') );

    // Chrome & Opera
    if( $(this).css('background-color').indexOf('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') == 0
       // Firefox & Internet Explorer
       || $(this).css('background-color').indexOf('transparent') == 0 ){

      $(this).css({"border":"2px solid blue"});
      console.log("Setting border to blue.\n\n");
    }else{
      $(this).css({"border":"2px solid red"});
      console.log("Setting border to red.\n\n");
    }
  });
  console.log("Red border means NOT transparent.");
});
```

```css
.one{
  background:grey;
  height:200px;
  padding:40px;
}
.two{
  background:transparent;
  height:200px;
  padding:40px;
}
.three{
  background:transparent;
  height:200px;
  padding:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      <span class="test">Hello - click me!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It may be best to check it in full page mode.
To test this in other browsers, you may use [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vxGqQm?editors=1111).

Comment: Looks good to me. By the way - it needs 'transparent' instead of rgba(0,0,0,0) in Firefox. I just run into it :-) Ok. for Chrome...

Comment: Thanks! I edited for this to be also working on Firefox.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution for Internet Exploder which doesn't obey...

Comment: oh--- thats welcome -- I tested you solution and it helps.
More tomorrow! I v got to leave.....

Comment: Done it... IE is not supporting `.includes()` method. So I used `indexOf()`.

Comment: Superb!!!  I changed the IF ..  `if( $(this).css('background-color').indexOf('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') == 0 || $(this).css('background-color').indexOf('transparent') == 0 ){` now is like sugar :-)

Comment: Yeah! same thing, but the code is easier to understand. I'll edit in this way. ;)

Comment: Hey, I just see that you were testing `background-color` from the start!!! I just hallucinated something here lol... ;)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that... But you helped me a lot!!!!! thanks